# Error when trying to reset knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js

In searching the interwebs the following code as part of my view model should work just fine:

```
function MyViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.name = ko.observable();
self.displayname = ko.observable();
self.description = ko.observable();

self.save = function () {
    $.post('/My/MVCControler',
        { Name: self.name(), DisplayName: self.displayname(), Description: self.description() },
        function success(data) {

            self.name(null);
            self.displayname(null);
            self.description(null);

            $('#MyDialog').modal('hide');
        });
}
}
```

However I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function` at `Name: self.name()`.

The end goal is to reset the view model on form submission.  I would also prefer to call ko.applyBindings only once as is best practice.

EDIT: After a great answer I realized that this.name was being created by a string somewhere other than my code.  Changing the variable name resolved the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't inadvertently assigned a string to it elsewhere?  The posted code looks fine.

Comment: and did you try: self.name('');???

Comment: I did try `self.name('')`.  Still not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be resetting **self.name** somewhere else in your code.  You mentioned that you've tried setting **self.name = ''** - is that code still in there?  Because if so, you're overwriting the observable object, and setting it as a string (hence the error message of 'string is not a function').

Look through your code (or post the rest of it up here), and make sure you're not setting **self.name = [anything]** elsewhere.

Comment: Well it was not me but that is what is happening.  Looks like I cant use name as a variable.

Comment: @WindRaven Depending on how you were declaring your viewmodel, perhaps you started to conflict with the global window.name

Comment: @JamesThorpe  Thanks for the research point.  It does look like that is exactly what is going on after some quick research.

Comment: @WindRaven That would seem to indicate that perhaps you're not declaring/instantiating your viewmodel correctly, as there shouldn't be a problem using `name` as a property name on an object

Comment: @JamesThorpe  earlier I edited to include the exact code I am using.  Ill definitely research more and I thank you for pointing me in the right direction.